# Initializer list in user-defined literal parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't know if it's possible but I want to do stuff like

```
int someval = 1;
if({1,2,3,4}_v.contains(someval ))
```

but when I try to define literal as:

```
std::vector<int> operator"" _v ( std::initializer_list<int> t )
{
    return std::vector<int> (t);
}
```

to accept initializer list of ints I get

```
 error: 'std::vector<int> operator"" _v(std::initializer_list<int> t)' has invalid argument list
```

Is there a way to do this? What I really want is to finally be rid of stuff like

```
if(value == 1 || value ==2 || value == 3 ...
```

Having to write stuff like this is really annoying, because you'd expect syntax to be

```
if value in (value1, value2 ...)
```

or something similar.

Comment: Out of interest, why `v`? Presumably as it stands for "vector"?

Comment: Yup, can be anything. I just want to have shorter if notation for multiple cases

Comment: Use C++17 and a fold expression over `||`; see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181949/2757035) to a similar question.

Comment: Frankly, I consider the example in that answer ugly. The thing you compare  shouldn't live in the same unseparated context as the things you compare to. Thankfully, fold expressions can be use a bit smarter to achieve what is needed with more clarity, there was a talk about that during C++ Russia by Björn Fahller. 

You can see the footnotes here: https://assets.ctfassets.net/oxjq45e8ilak/7lP3ueTFEJnmdVjGGjrgHI/e30dfcbff0630fb63389f3f3e734a1a3/100644_2039674689_Bjrn_Fahller_Modern_techniques_for_keeping_your_code_dry.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > you'd expect syntax to be
> >
> > ```
> > if value in (value1, value2 ...)
> > ```
> >
> > or something similar.

If you're willing to add *one extra character*, try this syntax:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T0, typename T1, std::size_t N>
bool operator *(const T0& lhs, const std::array<T1, N>& rhs) {
  return std::find(begin(rhs), end(rhs), lhs) != end(rhs);
}

template<class T0, class...T> std::array<T0, 1+sizeof...(T)> in(T0 arg0, T...args) {
  return {{arg0, args...}};
}

int main () {
  if( 2 *in(1,2,3) ) { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
  if( 4 *in(5,6,7,8) ) { std::cout << "Goodbye\n"; }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, now that's creative use of new stuff :)

Comment: On a side note - what did you read to gain such deep understanding of this stuff? I can't wrap it in my head enough to start using it. When I carefully read the code - it makes sense, but I can't bring myself in a state of mind to actually start writing things like that.

Comment: For general knowledge, I've been reading and writing C (and later C++) for 30 years. For templates specifically, StackOverflow, the C++ standard, and Google (in that order).

Comment: If someone is a custom syntax freak, which is probably not that good, they can `#define in *in_impl` ;)

Comment: Nah, the original answer works just fine. :) No need to #define anything.  Been using this past few months

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
bool contains(std::initializer_list<T> const & il, T const & x)
{
    for (auto const & z : il) { if (z == x) return true; }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool b = contains({1, 2, 3}, 5);  // false
```

Comment: Personally, I would just use `std::find`, rather than the loop.

Comment: Yes, this notation is the closest we can get it seems. Still too much braces but much easier to read than what is usually used.

Answer (score 5):

§13.5.8/3 says:

> The declaration of a literal operator shall have a
> parameter-declaration-clause equivalent to one of the following:
>
> ```
> const char*
> unsigned long long int
> long double
> char
> wchar_t
> char16_t
> char32_t
> const char*, std::size_t
> const wchar_t*, std::size_t
> const char16_t*, std::size_t
> const char32_t*, std::size_t
> ```

So it looks like you can't have a parameter of `initializer_list` type.

I can only think of the obvious as an alternative; if you don't mind typing a little more you can do something like

```
std::vector<int> v(std::initializer_list<int> l) {
    return { l };
}

int someval = 1;
if(v({1,2,3,4}).contains(someval))
```

Alternatively you could get wacky and write an operator overload for `initializer_list` (haven't tested though):

```
bool operator<=(std::intializer_list<int> l, int value) {
    return std::find(std::begin(l), std::end(l), value) != std::end(l);
}
```

And

```
if ({1, 2, 3, 4} <= 3)
```

should work...

**Actually nevermind, it doesn't.** You'll have to go with a normal function.

Comment: Bummer :( and I so hoped taht c++11 could allow a replacement for
if( val == 1 || val == 2 ||...)

Comment: Okay but what is the solution?! I can't think of anything better than tokenizing `"1,2,3,4"`

Comment: Also, what the heck is that text doing under §13.5! I would have expected it under §2.14.8, myself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well the question was is there a way to do the literal syntax, and the answer is no, but I'll add some alternative if I can think of a good one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well I think I've seen something for compile-time string manipulations so tokenising `"1,2,3,4"`  is probably feasible, but probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Is this a fundamental limitation, or simply not implemented for current standard?

Comment: Btw, I don't mind typing a little more. Thx very much, this will simplify stuff a lot. Should have though about it :)

Comment: Operator overload is nice but I am afraid this will hurt readability quite a lot. I mean - for ppl who will have to read the code other than me

Comment: @Zeks It's just not implemented for the current standard, I don't think there's a reason why besides time. And you can choose another operator if you think another is more readable, like `<<` or something.

Comment: The operator overload way doesn't work by the way. Plain if({1,2,3,4} << 1) fails with "error: expected primary-expression before '{' token"

Comment: As it seems, whatever it casts {1,2,3,4} to is not std::initializer_list<int>, because explicitly qualifying it as such works

Comment: @Zeks ah, sorry, I didn't test it, I assumed it should have worked.

Comment: Kerrek's post from below seems to be the shortest and most natural notation for the task then.