# Boolean and logical operators using characters, combining multiple tests

Tags: c++, char, boolean, logical-operators

I'm having an issue with boolean and logical operators. I'm trying to get `wantsToppings` to evaluate to `true` if toppings equals `'T'` or `'t'`, but this code evaluates to `true`, regardless of user input. I'm not sure what I am missing, but I know I gotta be missing something.

Thanks for any help.

```
cout << "Toppings wanted (T for toppings/N for no toppings)? ";
cin >> toppings;

if (toppings == 't' || 'T'){
    wantsToppings = true;
} else {
    wantsToppings = false;
}
```

Comment: This is basically a typo.

Comment: You have a simple typo :`toppings == 't' || toppings ==  'T'`. The `T` will be converted to `true` in your case.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values

Answer (score 3):

You are missing how logical operators work. Here is what you do:

```
if (toppings =='t' || 'T')
```

and here is how it's done:

```
if (toppings =='t' || toppings == 'T')
```

You don't really need the complexity of the `if` either, it could just be:

```
wantsToppings = (toppings == 't' || toppings == 'T');
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: Not to poke the beesnest, but what's the logic behind the statement? I cannot seem to find a good explanation of why you have to reference the variable twice.

Comment: `expression || expression`, so `toppings == 't'` is *one* expression, and `toppings == 'T'` is another, to test one or the other, you OR the two expressions.

Comment: @srallen87, FWIW, C++ can be more versatile given a library for it. For example, you could make `if (toppings <in> {'t', 'T'})` work. Of course you can also use `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` to halve the number of tests.

Comment: Sorry, I lied. Initializer lists can't be used like that. You could get close, though.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
if (toppings == 't' || 'T')
```

does not mean to `toppings` is either of `'t'` or `'T'`, but rather essentially (it's in fact a little bit more complicated than this once you factor in lazy evaluation):

- evaluates each sub-expression (the expression `toppings == 't'` and the expression `'T'`)
- convert results of those expressions to boolean values if required
- perform the logical or (`||`) of the above boolean values

Now `'T'` is a `char` which gets promoted to the boolean value `true`, hence the result is always true.

As others have pointed out, the expression you are looking for is

```
if (toppings == 't' || toppings == 'T')
```