# Why a template with an initializer_list argument misbehaves with string?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list, template-argument-deduction

Following [C++ Most efficient way to compare a variable to multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values), I am trying to build a template function with an `initializer_list` as an argument. The problem arises when I use strings only. I have the following code :

functions.hpp

```
template <typename T>
bool is_in(T const& val, initializer_list<T> const& liste)
{
   for (const auto& i : liste) 
      if (val == i) return true;
   return false;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "functions.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string test("hello");
   if (is_in(test, {"foo", "bar"}))
      cout << "good" << endl;
   else
      cout << "bad" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and I get the following error :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:18:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘is_in(std::string&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
main.cpp:18:34: note: candidate is:
In file included from personnage.hpp:11:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
functions.hpp:16:6: note: template<class T> bool is_in(const T&, const std::initializer_list<_Tp>&)
functions.hpp:16:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:34: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘std::basic_string<char>’ and ‘const char*’)
```

The thing I don't understand is : when instead of `string` I use `int` or `double` in my `main`, everything goes perfectly well... A quick and dirty fix was to declare `is_in` as a function of strings only, but it is not very satisfactory.

Does anyone know how to keep the template and use string all the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function template

```
template <typename T>
bool is_in(T const& val, initializer_list<T> const& liste)
```

both parameters will participate in [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call), and the types deduced from each are different. `T` is deducted as `std::string` from the first parameter and as `char const *` from the second (user defined conversions are not considered during template argument deduction, so the implicit conversion from `char const *` to `std::string` doesn't come into the picture), which leads to the compilation errors.

There are different ways to fix this problem. One would be to construct `string`s within the *braced-init-list* you pass to `is_in`, which can be done very succinctly if you can use C++14's [`std::string_literals`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

if (is_in(test, {"foo"s, "bar"s}))
//                    ^       ^
```

Another would be to construct an `initializer_list<string>` and pass that to `is_in`

```
if (is_in(test, initializer_list<string>{"foo", "bar"}))
```

You could also redefine `is_in` so that the template type parameters for the two parameter types are distinct, after all, you don't care about them being the same, you just need them to comparable by `operator==`

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool is_in(T const& val, initializer_list<U> const& liste)
```

Yet another option is to prevent one of the function parameters from participating in template argument deduction.

```
template<typename T>
struct identity
{  using type = T;  };

template <typename T>
bool is_in(T const& val, initializer_list<typename identity<T>::type> const& liste)
```

Above the `T` in the second parameter is a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), so only the first parameter takes part in template argument deduction.

---

Finally, `is_in` can be replaced by [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

```
auto elems = {"foo", "bar"};
if (any_of(begin(elems), end(elems), [&](string const& s) { return s == test; }))
```

If you want to avoid the lambda expression boilerplate, you can use [`boost::algorithm::any_of_equal`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/algorithm/doc/html/header/boost/algorithm/cxx11/any_of_hpp.html).

```
auto elems = {"foo", "bar"};
if (boost::algorithm::any_of_equal(elems, test))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple:

The compiler have no idea if it should use `const char*` or `std::string` from your strings.

If you write

```
if (is_in(test, {std::string("foo"), std::string("bar")}))
```

it works as expected.

This is also what your compiler gives you as a hint:

> main.cpp:18:34: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘std::basic_string’ and ‘const char*’)