# OR operator in for loop C

Tags: c, loops

I have no idea how the following code returns 10. I expected that the x>2||(y%2) part meant that x should either be bigger than two or bigger than y%2.

```
int x, y = 1;
for (x = 10; x > 2 || (y % 2); x--) {
y = y + 1;
}
printf ("%d\n", y);
```

when I change it to the following, I get my expected output (11):

```
int x, y = 1;
for (x = 10; x > 2 || x > (y % 2); x--) {
y = y + 1;
}
printf ("%d\n", y);
```

how is the second code different from the first one?

Comment: nope, `x > 2 || (y % 2)` means "`x > 2`" or "`y` is odd". how could the compiler could understand what you want ?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values

Comment: You will want to learn about operator precedence

Comment: x > 2 || (y % 2) does not evaluate as x > 2 or x > (y % 2). Instead, the integer y % 2 is is converted to a boolean as 1 -> true and 0 -> false

Comment: Thanks a lot Jean-François and acai, that clears things up.

Comment: @imabug this isn't operator precedence. Put the parentheses anywhere you want, you cannot achieve what OP wants. it's just that `||` isn't distributed to each one of the conditions.

Comment: if someone finds a good duplicate of that one, I'll close it. I haven't found one specifically for c or even c++, even if this question comes back a lot in python for instance.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This is true, but OP being more familiar with operator precedence rules wouldn't have needed to ask the question

Comment: it's _not_ operator precedence. Operator precedence is when you have `a + b * c` and the result is incorrect, now adding parentheses like `(a + b) * c` then the result is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Most efficient way to compare a variable to multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x > 2 || (y % 2)
```

first tests `x > 2`, and if this is false, then tests `(y % 2)` (`y` is odd).

The `||` operator doesn't and cannot apply to the `>` operator, the `||` operation is performed exactly once, not twice. It's the C variant of the classic Python mistake showcased here: [How do I test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values), where trying to use natural language in a computer language fails.

(BTW it's *not* operator precedence, operator precedence would be between that expression and `x > (2 || (y % 2))`, still not what you're looking for)

Also related: [C++ Most efficient way to compare a variable to multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values)