# how to tell if a enum class value is in a specified range of enum class in a more effective way?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

```
enum class color {
    red,
    black,
    white,
    yellow,
    green,
    blue,
};
color c;
if(c == color::red && c == color::black || c == color::green -etc.)
```

The last statement is too fussy,is there any better way to do it like 
`if(c in(color::red,color::black,color::green))`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181949/7699037) might help

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as an enum class is not just a bunch of values... anyways you could just do if(c >= color::red && c <= color::blue) Or add some kind of begin/end values like here: https://godbolt.org/g/kFgSVR