# How to correctly use the if statement for this function?

Tags: c++

I seem to be having a problem with an if statement in one of the functions of my program.

I want the line of code to stop until the correct variable is displayed, while also outputting an error message. However, the code continues no matter if the wrong or correct variable is entered, and the error message is displayed with it as well.

Here is the section of code with the if statement

```
string get_class(){

    string char_class;

    cout<<"Choose A Character Class!"<<endl;    
    cout<<"The Cleric, a holy disciple!   Select C."<<endl;
    cout<<"The Fighter, an unstoppable warrior!  Select F."<<endl;
    cout<<"The Paladin, a holy warrior!  Select P."<<endl;
    cout<<"The Rogue, a sneaky thief!  Select R."<<endl;
    cout<<"The Wizard, a wizened magician!  Select W."<<endl;
    cin>>classSelection;

    if(classSelection != "C"||"c"||"F"||"f"||"P"||"p"||"R"||"r"||"W"||"w")
        cout<<"Please Enter Given Selections"<<endl;

    return char_class; 

}
```

I apologize if not enough of the program was given, or if everything in this snippet looks unorganized.

Comment: I think you are searching for a `switch`.

Comment: @JVApen Doen's work with `std::string`

Comment: Oh yeah, sounds like a mistake I've read over

Comment: _@EarlyProgrammer_ The `||` operator doesn't do what you think it does in that condition.

Comment: `"C"||"c"||"F"||"f"||"P"||"p"||"R"||"r"||"W"||"w"` will evaluate to `true` since at least one of them is "not false" (actually they all are). So you basically have `if(classSelection != true)...`

Comment: How would I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate [C++ Most efficient way to compare a variable to multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values)

Comment: In the case of this code how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify the example. Your code does not work for the same reason that this one will not:

```
int x = 2;
if(x == 1 || 2) { ... }
```

That's because `||` operator does not concatenate in such way. The above example evaluates the `x == 1` (`false`) and that ORs it (`||`) with `2`, like so:

```
if(false || 2) { ... } // after evaluating of x == 1
```

We now have `false || 2`. In `C++`, any non-zero numeric value evaluates to `true`, so we end up with `false || true`, which is `true`.

But it seems like it *works* in this example, right?

It only appears to. Replace the `2` with `3` and the code will *still* be evaluated to `true`, even though `x` is neither `1` nor `3`.

#### How to fix the issue?

In case of small combinations, one should just correctly provide all the expressions:

```
if(x == 1 || x == 2) { ... }
```

instead of:

```
if(x == 1 || 2) { ... }
```

So in your example you would need:

```
if(classSelection != "C" || classSelection != "c" || classSelection != "F" ||  ... )
```

But that still wouldn't do what you want. You don't want to know whether `classSelection` is not equal to, for instance, `"C"` **or** not equal to `"c"`. You want to know if it's not equal to `"C"` **and** not equal to `"c"`, so you'd actually want:

```
if(classSelection != "C" && classSelection != "c" && classSelection != "F" &&  ... )
```

And your example would require some typing. Another approach, slightly less eficient, but arguably more readable, would be to store all the possible matches in a data structure and use a standard algorithm, such as [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<const char*> not_accepted= {
            "C", "c", "F", "f", "P", "p", "R", "r", "W", "w"
    };

    std::string choice = "f"; // provided by user

    bool valid = std::all_of(not_accepted.cbegin(), not_accepted.cend(),
            [&](auto arg){
        return choice != arg;
    });

    std::cout << "valid? - " << std::boolalpha << valid;
}
```

`std::all_of` takes a range and a predicate and returns `true`, if all the elements satisfy the predicate. Here, the range is our `not_accepted` vector and our predicate is represented as a lambda, which will compare every single element of that vector with our `choice` string.

To optimise, one could replace `std::vector` with a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` and check for elements being present in a set. That would get rid of an algorithm call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<const char*> not_accepted = {
            "C", "c", "F", "f", "P", "p", "R", "r", "W", "w"
    };

    std::string choice = "f";
    bool valid = not_accepted.find("f") == not_accepted.end();

    std::cout << "valid? - " << std::boolalpha << valid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My personal favourite

```
while("CcFfPpRrWw"s.find(classSelection) == string::npos)
{
    cout << "Please Enter Given Selections" << endl;
    cin >> classSelection;
}
```

In your original code you made the rookie mistake of or'ing possible candidates for selection. These will individually evaluate to true, causing the whole expression to always evaluate to true.

My code puts all the choices in a temporary string and searches it for the inputted char. string::npos is returned if it is not found, triggering the while loop.

Comment: Simpler and better solution that my approaches using `std::vector` or `std::[unordered]_set`. I somehow always keep forgetting about `std::string::find`. If you also provide explanation to why the OP's approach does not work and how yours work, I will happily upvote your answer.