# what is wrong with this execution of OR operand in C

Tags: c, char, logical-or

When I separate the `str[i]` with all the vowels it works, what is wrong with the current execution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
 
int main() {

    int k = 0;
    char str[100];

    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
        if(str[i] == ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')){
           k++;
        }
     }
     printf("%d",k);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Most efficient way to compare a variable to multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When I separate the str[i] with all the vowels it works...*

This is due to the fact that you are comparing a character with a boolean expression, which will be either `1` or `0`, this comparison will never be true, `str` will not have any characters with `0` or `1` codes, these are non-printable control characters.

In practical terms `('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')` is equivalent to `(97 || 101 || 105 || 111 || 117)` these are each character's ASCII codes as an example, other encodings will have different codes, this is how your program really sees them.

Anyway, this sequence of `OR`'s will evaluate to `1`, so let's say `str[i]` is `'a'`, the comparison will be `97 == 1`, this is of course false, the same for the other vowels, so `k` will never be incremented.

Of course separating the characters one by one will work because each individual comparison will now work as expected.

If you don't like the long `if` you can use :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
  int k = 0;
  char str[100];

  scanf("%[^\n]", str);

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
      switch(str[i]){
          case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
              k++;
      }
  }
  printf("%d", k);
}
```

Or you can use [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) as posted by Vlad.

---

On a side  note, `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);` should be `scanf("%[^\n]", str);`, the `%[^\n]` specifier doesn't need an `s` at the end, if you include it it means that `scanf` will be expecting a string ending in `s`.

Answer (score 3):

It compares `str[i]` with the expression `'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'`, which gets evaluated to `true`, which value is equal to `1`. Think about characters as integers, which `char` correspond to (in ASCII), then your expression would be `97 || 101 || ...`, which is certainly `true`.

To make this work as intended, you need to split all comparisons:

```
str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'u'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
> unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

So this primary expression within the condition of the if statement

```
('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')
```

is always evaluates to integer `1` because at least the first operand `'a'` is  unequal to `0`.

So in fact this if statement

```
if(str[i]==('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')){
```

is equivalent to

```
if( str[i] == 1 ){
```

and it evaluates to logical true only in one case when `str[i]` is equal to `1`.

You need to write

```
if( str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e'|| str[i] == 'i'|| str[i] == 'o'|| str[i] == 'u' ){
```

Another approach is to use the standard function `strchr`. For example

```
if ( strchr( "aeiou", str[i] ) ) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot that you should use operators with two operands, so the compiler could recognize each operation and label them as True or False. use this code instead:

````
 
int main() {
    int k=0;
    char str[100];
      scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        if((str[i]== 'a')||(str[i] == 'e')||(str[i] == 'i')||(str[i] == 'o')||(str[i] == 'u')){
        k++;
        }
    }
 printf("%d",k);
}```
````